# How to correctly pad by PKCS#7 for AES?

Tags: aes, padding

I want to implement AES-CBC mode with PKCS#7 padding, along with a way to validate a correct padding given the ciphertext. My initial understanding was that for an input of size `n` (where `n` is less than 16) PKCS#7 pads `16-n` until the input becomes divisible by 16 (or equal to 16 in this case). But later I realized that this would make it impossible to validate a correct padding.

Then I found out that you always pad at least 1 byte when doing PKCS#7 padding (with byte `01` if length of input is divisible by the desired amount). Is this understanding correct? If so, should I divide my input into blocks with size of 15 bytes (with 16th byte being the pad byte)?

Comment: Instead of guessing, did you consider looking at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS#5_and_PKCS#7) or [the specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2630#section-6.3) (actually that's CMS, the successor to PKCS7, because it has proper hyperlinks and 2315 doesn't, but this content is the same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then I found out that you always pad at least 1 byte when doing PKCS#7 padding (with byte `01` if length of input is divisible by the desired amount). Is this understanding correct?

Actually, if the input was already a multiple of 16 bytes, the padding would consist of 16 `10` (hex) bytes, which you would append to the end of the input.  Then, the padded input will then be a multiple of 16 bytes (which, with this padding method, is always the case, even if the original input was an odd length).

> If so, should I divide my input into blocks with size of 15 bytes (with 16th byte being the pad byte)?

No; you need to add padding only to the end of the message - there is no reason (or permission, as far as PKCS#7 is concerned) to add padding to the intermediate blocks.

Comment: I see, thank you for the answer